# Android studio 3.0.1 problems??Possibly need to sync project with gradle files?

Tags: android-studio, ide, android-gradle-plugin

Okay I've been trying to find the button to sync project with gradle files but I can't find it at all on android studio 3.0.1?Please help.Also I tried ctrl+shift+A and typing sync but clicking on the option didn't do anything?

Answer (score 0):

May be you import your project incorrectly. Try to import again.
Also try to clean and rebuild project.
Or try [Android Studio 3.1 stable](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/android-studio-3-1.html)

Comment: Can you run new project form AndroidStudio?